# discord.py streaming role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot give streaming role everyone who started a stream and then take it it away when the stream is over. In theory it works because it gave me the role when I started the stream but when the stream was over it didn't took it away. It seems like giving the role works with every member but it can't take it away from som member. I tried it on multiple accaunts with the same roles and same permissions and it seems like it's completely random if it works with someone or not. Also I'm not getting any error.

the code is too long to pase but here is the part that does this:

````
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def check_live_streams():
    guild = bot.get_guild(879081332590927892)
    members = guild.members
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1093595952562049114)
    for member in members:
        is_streaming = False
        for activity in member.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, discord.Streaming):
                is_streaming = True
            if is_streaming:
                if role not in member.roles:
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print(f"Rang hozzáadva: {member.name}")
            else:
                if role in member.roles:
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                    print(f"Rang levéve: {member.name}")```
````

I tried making it take away the role from eveyone in every loop by putting another line in between like this:

```
for member in members:
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

but it still didn't take away the role